# How can I check if all radiogroups have a selected answer when populated by a recyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I've only been writing code for a couple months and I'm still fairly newbie to a lot of techniques, but I'm working on a math training quiz for my 5 year old son. I've been trying to a few different "games" to play and challenge himself. I finished a time-trial yesterday, and a pattern match last week but now I'm stuck on the current game, which is a levels challenge. The player must answer 10 questions correctly to move to the next level (where the questions get harder).

I'm using a RecyclerView to create the questions. Each question is populated with random integers, and possible answers are selectable as RadioButtons.

[image: screenshot]

So far I've been able to figure out how to add the formatting and update the ViewHolder, but now I'm stuck with trying to create a method in my Fragment to check for all questions answered. I believe that has to be done in the Fragment, since the Fragment is where I define how many questions to create and where the random numbers are generated and passed into the ArrayList that the Recycler Adapter uses to update the View Holder.

I hope that I'm explaining myself well enough, so my question is how can I check that all radiogroups meet the following parameters:

- Has a selected radioButton
- Is answered correctly (if they're answered incorrectly, they won't move to the next level, but instead will be given a new set of the same difficulty questions.

Here is my Fragment Class:

```
public class FragmentLevelChallenge extends Fragment{

public static final String TAG = "LevelChallengeFragment";

RecyclerView recyclerView;
RVAdapterMulti adapterMulti;
private List<multiquestion> QuestionsMulti;

int firstDig;
int secondDig;
int correctAnswer;
int incorrectOne;
int incorrectTwo;
int incorrectThree;
int thisPosition;

int selectedAnswers;
int questionsAnswered;

//levelChallenge defines the current challenge level
int levelChallenge;
int maxBound = 10;
int minBound = 1;
int adjustBound = 1;
RadioGroup radioGroupRecycler;



public static FragmentLevelChallenge newInstance() {
    FragmentLevelChallenge fragment = new FragmentLevelChallenge();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_level_challenge, container, false);

    levelChallenge = 1;

    QuestionsMulti = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_display_multi);
    radioGroupRecycler = view.findViewById(R.id.radio_group_multi);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    TextView levelsText = view.findViewById(R.id.level_challenge);
    levelsText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
    initializeRecyclerAdapter();
    createQuestionBatch();
    return view;
}

private void createQuestionBatch() {
    //Integer values to define the minimum, maximum and adjustment for random integers
    if (selectedAnswers == 5) {
        levelChallenge++;
    }

    //Checks the current level to determine the boundaries for difficulty of random integers
    switch (levelChallenge) {
        case 1: //If level 1 (bounds 10,1,1)
            maxBound = 10;
            minBound = 1;
            adjustBound = 1;
            break;
        case 2: //If level 2 (bounds 20,1,4)
            maxBound = 20;
            minBound = 1;
            adjustBound = 4;
            break;
        case 3: //If level 3 (bounds 25,10,5)
            maxBound = 25;
            minBound = 10;
            adjustBound = 5;
            break;
        case 4: //If level 4 (bounds 30,10,7)
            maxBound = 30;
            minBound = 10;
            adjustBound = 7;
            break;
        case 5: //If level 5 (bounds 50,10,9)
            maxBound = 50;
            minBound = 10;
            adjustBound = 9;
            break;
        case 6: //If level 6 (bounds 75,10,15)
            maxBound = 75;
            minBound = 10;
            adjustBound = 15;
            break;
        case 7: //If level 7 (bounds 100,10,18)
            maxBound = 100;
            minBound = 10;
            adjustBound = 18;
            break;
        //If level 8 (bounds random integers?)
    }

    //Creates the random integers for math functions
    int questionsToFillRecycler = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < questionsToFillRecycler; i++) {
        final Random r = new Random();
        Random position = new Random();
        thisPosition = position.nextInt(4 - 1) + 1;
        //Creates the array list for incorrect answers
        firstDig = r.nextInt(maxBound - minBound) + adjustBound;
        secondDig = r.nextInt(maxBound - minBound) + adjustBound;
        if (firstDig < secondDig) {
            correctAnswer = secondDig - firstDig;
            incorrectOne = secondDig - firstDig - 1;
            incorrectTwo = secondDig - firstDig + 2;
            incorrectThree = (secondDig + firstDig) - 2;
        } else {
            correctAnswer = firstDig + secondDig;
            incorrectOne = secondDig + firstDig - 2;
            incorrectTwo = secondDig + firstDig + 1;
            incorrectThree = (firstDig - secondDig) + 3;
        }

        //Convert integer to string values
        String firstNumber = String.valueOf(firstDig);
        String secondNumber = String.valueOf(secondDig);
        String firstIncorrect = String.valueOf(incorrectOne);
        String secondIncorrect = String.valueOf(incorrectTwo);
        String thirdIncorrect = String.valueOf(incorrectThree);
        String correct = String.valueOf(correctAnswer);
        List<String> answers = new Vector<>();
        answers.add(correct);
        answers.add(firstIncorrect);
        answers.add(secondIncorrect);
        answers.add(thirdIncorrect);
        Collections.shuffle(answers);
        if (firstDig < secondDig) {
            //Checks if 1st integer is less than 2nd integer
            QuestionsMulti.add(new multiquestion(secondNumber, firstNumber, answers.get(0), "-", answers.get(1), answers.get(2), answers.get(3)));
        } else if (firstDig > secondDig) {
            //Checks if 1st integer is greater than 2nd integer
            QuestionsMulti.add(new multiquestion(secondNumber, firstNumber, answers.get(0), "+", answers.get(1), answers.get(2), answers.get(3)));
        } else {
            //Checks if 1st integer is greater than 2nd integer
            QuestionsMulti.add(new multiquestion(secondNumber, firstNumber, answers.get(0), "+", answers.get(1), answers.get(2), answers.get(3)));
        }
        //Updates the RecyclerView Adapter
        adapterMulti.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

private void initializeRecyclerAdapter() {
    adapterMulti = new RVAdapterMulti(QuestionsMulti);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterMulti);
}
}
```

And here is my RecyclerAdapter:

```
public class RVAdapterMulti extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapterMulti.ViewHolder> {


private static String TAG = "RadioMultiAdapter";
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<multiquestion> QuestionsMulti;
private int questionsAnswered;

private AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener onSelect;

public RVAdapterMulti(List<multiquestion> QuestionMulti) {
    this.QuestionsMulti = QuestionMulti;
}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item_multi, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    multiquestion currentQuestion = QuestionsMulti.get(position);
    holder.setFirstDigit(currentQuestion.firstNumber);
    holder.setSecondDigit(currentQuestion.secondNumber);
    holder.setMathFunction(currentQuestion.mathFunc);
    holder.setOptions(currentQuestion, position);

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (QuestionsMulti == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return QuestionsMulti.size();
    }
}


class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private LinearLayout linearLayoutContainer;
    private TextView firstDigitView;
    private TextView secondDigitView;
    private TextView mathFunctionView;
    private TextView mathAnswerView;
    private RadioGroup radioGroupOptions;
    private RadioButton radioButtonOne, radioButtonTwo;
    private RadioButton radioButtonThree, radioButtonFour;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        firstDigitView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.first_digit);
        secondDigitView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.second_digit);
        mathFunctionView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.math_function);
        mathAnswerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.math_answer);
        radioGroupOptions = itemView.findViewById(R.id.radio_group_multi);
        radioButtonOne = itemView.findViewById(R.id.radio_button_one);
        radioButtonTwo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.radio_button_two);
        radioButtonThree = itemView.findViewById(R.id.radio_button_three);
        radioButtonFour = itemView.findViewById(R.id.radio_button_four);

    }

    public void setFirstDigit(String firstDigit) {
        firstDigitView.setText(firstDigit);

    }
    public void setSecondDigit(String secondDigit) {
        secondDigitView.setText(secondDigit);

    }
    public void setMathFunction(String mathFunction) {
        mathFunctionView.setText(mathFunction);
    }



    public void setOptions(final multiquestion question, int position) {
        radioGroupOptions.setTag(position);
        radioButtonOne.setText(question.correct);
        radioButtonTwo.setText(question.incorrectOne);
        radioButtonThree.setText(question.incorrectTwo);
        radioButtonFour.setText(question.incorrectThree);

        if (question.mathFunc.equals("+")) {
            question.correctSolution = Integer.parseInt(question.firstNumber) + Integer.parseInt(question.secondNumber);
        } else {
            question.correctSolution = Integer.parseInt(question.firstNumber) - Integer.parseInt(question.secondNumber);
        }

        if(question.isAnswered) {
            radioGroupOptions.check(question.checkedId);
        } else {
            radioGroupOptions.check(-1);
        }
        radioGroupOptions.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                int pos = (int) group.getTag();
                multiquestion que = QuestionsMulti.get(pos);
                que.isAnswered = true;
                que.checkedId = checkedId;
                radioGroupOptions.setClickable(false);
                radioButtonOne.setClickable(false);
                radioButtonTwo.setClickable(false);
                radioButtonThree.setClickable(false);
                radioButtonFour.setClickable(false);
                questionsAnswered = questionsAnswered + 1;
                mathAnswerView.setText(String.valueOf(question.correctSolution));
                String radioOneText = String.valueOf(radioButtonOne.getText());
                String radioTwoText = String.valueOf(radioButtonTwo.getText());
                String radioThreeText = String.valueOf(radioButtonThree.getText());
                String radioFourText = String.valueOf(radioButtonFour.getText());

                switch (que.checkedId) {
                    case R.id.radio_button_one:
                        if(radioOneText.equals(String.valueOf(question.correctSolution))) {
                            mathAnswerView.setTextColor(group.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorCorrect));
                        } else {
                            mathAnswerView.setTextColor(group.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorIncorrect));
                        }
                        break;
                    case R.id.radio_button_two:
                        if(radioTwoText.equals(String.valueOf(question.correctSolution))) {
                            mathAnswerView.setTextColor(group.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorCorrect));
                        } else {
                            mathAnswerView.setTextColor(group.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorIncorrect));
                        }
                        break;
                    case R.id.radio_button_three:
                        if(radioThreeText.equals(String.valueOf(question.correctSolution))) {
                            mathAnswerView.setTextColor(group.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorCorrect));
                        } else {
                            mathAnswerView.setTextColor(group.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorIncorrect));
                        }
                        break;
                    case R.id.radio_button_four:
                        if(radioFourText.equals(String.valueOf(question.correctSolution))) {
                            mathAnswerView.setTextColor(group.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorCorrect));
                        } else {
                            mathAnswerView.setTextColor(group.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorIncorrect));
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way will be to keep track of correct answers in your `QuestionMulti` list (you should refactor that to camel case by convention). Add an attribute to your `multiquestion` (should be `MultiQuestion`) class called `answeredCorrectly` with a default value of `false`. 
Then every time `onCheckChanged` is called, set the value at that position in the list and also loop through the list to check if every answer is correct.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.. so then how do I pass that information along to the Fragment, so that when I click a button the check occurs to see if all 10 questions have been answered correctly. Since my RVAdapterMulti doesn't know how many questions are created, I can't have the check occur there, unless I don't understand the concept of a recyclerview correctly...

Comment: Your ```RVAdapterMulti``` does know how many questions are created. It is stored here ```private List<multiquestion> QuestionsMulti;```. All you have to do is make that field public (or use a getter) and then you can write ```adapterMulti.getQuestionsMulti()``` in your fragment and loop through that list to check for correct answers

Comment: Did that answer your questions? Anything else let me know. Otherwise please give me the accepted answer points :D